# Makefiles and wildcards

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu

Alright so this is my current setup for a makefile. There are files which are named `public01.c`, `public02.c`, etc. I'm trying to make object files for each of them using the `public*.o` label with a wildcard.

```
public*.o: public*.c hashtable.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c public*.c

public*: public*.o
    $(CC) -o public* public*.o
```

However, when I try and run the makefile, I get this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `public*.c', needed by `public*.o'.  Stop.
```

I guess it's treating `public*.c` as a label and not a wildcard as I'd like. I read about `$(wildcard pattern...)` function and played around with it, but I didn't really understand it or got it to work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**:  that syntax does not work the way you want it to.  The correct way to do what you want in GNU make syntax is to use pattern rules:

```
public%.o: public%.c hashtable.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

public%: public%.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

**Long answer**:  This:

```
public*.o: public*.c hashtable.h
```

does not mean what you want it to mean.  Assuming you have several file `public01.c`, etc., and no files `public01.o`, etc., at the start of your build, that syntax is equivalent to this:

```
public*.o: public01.c public02.c public03.c ... hashtable.h
```

That is, if `public01.o`, etc., do not exist, then make will use the literal string `public*.o` as the filename.  If some of the `.o` files do exist, then that syntax is equivalent to this:

```
public01.o public02.o ...: public01.c public02.c ... hashtable.h
```

Seems like what you want right?  But that's a common misunderstanding with make, because in fact that line is exactly the same as this:

```
public01.o: public01.c public02.c ... hashtable.h
public02.o: public01.c public02.c ... hashtable.h
```

That is -- every `.o` file has a dependency on every `.c` file!  The correct way to do what you want is to use a pattern rule, as shown above.

Comment: +1, but don't you need `public$*.c`, `public$*.o`, and `public$*` in the recipes, or better yet `$<` and `$@`?

Comment: @eriktous: whoops, that was a copy-paste-o.  Fixed now, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually occurs because the gcc thinks the file doesn't exist. Make sure it exists and make sure you're in the directory where it exists, and then it should work.

Also, any reason you don't have $(CFLAGS) for the public*? Why exactly is it public*? Simply having "public" would suffice I believe.