# Cannot use wildcard in kernel module makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kernel-module

I am pretty familiar with Makefiles and kernel modules, but recently I got a problem in my Makefile that doesn't make any sense -- on using wildcards. 
To demonstrate this, I am compiling a hello world kernel module from scratch.
The directory structure is like this:

```
hello_mod/
   | 
   --- hello.c
   |
   --- Makefile
```

Here is the actual makefile :

```
CFILES := $(wildcard hello.c*)
#CFILES := hello.c
OBJS := $(CFILES:.c=.o)

KSRC := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m += hello_world.o
hello_world-y := $(OBJS)

all:    
        @echo $(CFILES)
        $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$$PWD modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$$PWD clean

.PHONY: clean
```

The problem is that even though the commented $(CFILES) and the uncommented $(CFILES) are exactly the same, the build fails on using the first $(CFILES) with the following error:

```
*** No rule to make target `/home/test/hello_mod/hello_world.c', needed by
/home/test/hello_mod/hello_world.o'.  Stop.
```

If the commented $(CFILES) is used, it works perfectly.

If someone wants to test this out, I'm including the source for the hello world source which is hello.c :

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int mod_init()
{
        printk("Hello\n");
        return 0;
}

static void mod_exit()
{
        printk("Bye world\n");    
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

Does anyone know why it is behaving as such? And I need to use wildcards in the makefile. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to see this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577176/makefiles-and-wildcards

Comment: That question has nothing to do with mine, he/she is using "*" in a rule. I'm using wildcard operator to list the sources into a variable.

Comment: Why do you use `$(dir)` in `CFILES` definition? Did you use `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`?

Comment: `$(dir)` is part of `foreach`. I don't think there is any other way to do this. `remake -x` doesn't really give me anything useful, it keeps pointing to the fact that there is no such rule.

Comment: Are you sure that the current directory is the correct one when the `wildcard` function happens to be executed? You should better use absolute paths.

Comment: Current directory is correct. I'm getting same value for `$(CPATH)`. I think absolute paths to object files don't work properly when Kbuild is used. I tried something like `CFILES := $(addprefix $(realpath .)/,$(CFILES))` and it doesn't still compile.

Comment: Can you show us the makefile in `/lib/module/$(shell uname -r)/build/`? I suspect it's doing something naughty.

Comment: Its the location of the kernel build system and headers (which is pretty big to put here). I haven't modified the kernel in any way. In fact, you could try on your machine right now (assuming `kernel-devel` or `linux-headers` package is installed)
I have tried with `ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 kernel 3.8.0` and also `fedora 14 x86_64 with 2.6.35-45`

Comment: I don't have ubuntu nor fedora to play with at the moment. I'd suggest you make a copy of this makefile, `Makefile2`, then test `make -f Makefile2`, then start removing things gradually, e.g. take `$(DRV_NAME)-y` out of `Makefile2`, then remove the `all` rule from `Makefile`. That will simplify things, and might give a clue as to which way the information is actually flowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two makes happening here.  The first really only relies on the KSRC variable and the recursive make call.  The second make only needs the `CFILES`, `OBJS`, `obj-m`, and `hello_world-y` variables, and doesn't make use of the `all:` target.  So your debug is showing that CFILES is set correctly for the first Make, where it's not being used, and is not showing it in the second make, where it is.

You're wildcard expanding from a different directory, and not picking up the right files.  Try this for CFILES:

```
CFILES := $(notdir $(wildcard $M/hello.c*))
```

Comment: Ok this works! Just to clarify, `$(CFLAGS)` is a simply expanded variable and according to the make manual `it contains their values as of the time this variable was defined.`, so why is it getting expanded again?

Comment: If you use :=, the right side is expanded immediately, and kept FOR THE REST OF THE CURRENT MAKE PROCESS.  In this case, the kbuild system involves a second invocation of `make`.  In that second invocation, everything starts from scratch.  The only information that passes from first make to the second is on the command line, as in M=$$PWD.  That's why I use $M to expand the directory in the second make process.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SRCDIRS := subdir1 subdir2
 CFILES := $(strip $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
```

should probably be (see `foreach` [example in documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function))

```
 SRCDIRS := subdir1 subdir2
 CFILES := $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
```

(no need to `$(strip`), ....  or perhaps

```
 CFILES := $(wildcard  {subdir1,subdir2}/*.c)
```

Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), probably as `remake -x`, to debug such issues.

Comment: Does this work for you? I have already tested without `strip`, it doesn't work.