# How to autofill "obj-y" or "xxx-objs" in linux kernel module Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

"**obj-y**" or "**xxx-objs**" tags can be manually written in a **Makefile** like this:

```
obj-y += aaa.o bbb.o ccc.o ddd.o
```

```
xxx-objs += aaa.o bbb.o ccc.o ddd.o
```

it work well when do **make** cmd.

**BUT**!!!!: when I change this **Makefile** like this:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := $(foreach f,$(SRCS),$(f:%.c=%.o))
 
obj-y += $(OBJS)
```

unfortually, this Makefile does not work!

I want konwn why and how to autofill this tags?

---

**NEW QUESTION:**

also, I found some method in some url in following answer. and I do just like that.
but I met **something strange**.
My files \ dirs like this:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── moduleA
│   ├── a0.c
│   ├── a0.h
│   ├── a1.c
│   ├── a1.h
│   └── Makefile
└── moduleB
    ├── b0.c
    ├── b0.h
    ├── b1.c
    ├── b1.h
    └── Makefile
```

the **top Makefile** is:

```
dirs := $(shell ls -d */)

obj-y := moduleA/ moduleB/

all:
    make -C common/
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
    $(foreach N,$(dirs),cat Module.symvers > $(N)Module.symvers;)
    @make clean_this

clean_this:
    rm -rf Module.symvers modules.order .tmp_versions .cache.mk

clean: clean_this
    $(foreach N,$(dirs),make -C $(N) clean;)
```

and Makefile in dir moduleA:

```
MODULE_NAME += module-a

obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o

SRCS := $(notdir $(wildcard $M/*.c))
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += $(OBJS)
$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += ../common/libcommon.a

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(shell pwd)
    
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.m* *.ko *.t* .*.t* *.s* *.o* .*_* .*cm .*.cmd .*.mk *.a .*.o.d
```

Makefile in dir moduleB also like this:

```
MODULE_NAME += module-b

obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o

SRCS := $(notdir $(wildcard $M/*.c))
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += $(OBJS)
$(MODULE_NAME)-objs += ../common/libcommon.a

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(shell pwd)
    
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.m* *.ko *.t* .*.t* *.s* *.o* .*_* .*cm .*.cmd .*.mk *.a .*.o.d
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Strange things** , when I do `make` cmd in subdir **moduleA** or **moduleB**, all things work well.

**But**, When I do `make` cmd in **top dir** , the result ***.ko** did not contains **.o** files which it really need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use wildcard in kernel module makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041772/cannot-use-wildcard-in-kernel-module-makefile)

Comment: Also see that question and my answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428882/linux-out-of-tree-module-build-issue

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for your help. but I met something strange. I post new answer to discribe my question.

Comment: "I post new answer to discribe my question." - No, do not do that. An **answer post** is only for **solutions**. If you have tried some code for your original problem, and found that code to be not-working, you may describe this attempt in the **question post** (by editing it).

Comment: oooh, i am sorry for that...now, i delete it

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code as example :As am not sure how linux kernel module makefile works with wildcard

```
SRCS := $(notdir $(wildcard $M/*.c))
#SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
obj-y += $(OBJS)
```